# Interpertation of coefficient and marginal effect in logit model

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, marginal-effect

My problem is that I am not able to interpret my results. I am confusing coefficient and marginal effect interpertation.

```
Dependent Variable: PVO         
Method: ML - Binary Logit  (Newton-Raphson / Marquardt steps)   
Sample: 1 80                


Variable    Coefficient Std. Error  z-Statistic Prob.   marginal effect


C   2.657619    3.658793    0.726365    0.4676  
EOH -0.09404    0.167246    -0.5623 0.5739  -0.013880599
PRO -5.5753 2.310915    -2.4126 0.0158  -0.822914575
CES -0.53666    0.4531  -1.18443    0.2362  -0.079211606
NFM 1.856624    0.945254    1.964154    0.0495  0.274037702
HEX -0.0005 0.000384    -1.29073    0.1968  -0.000073062
LIA -0.19821    0.374566    -0.52917    0.5967  -0.029255501
FUE -1.63151    2.169999    -0.75185    0.4521  -0.240811319
RIH -0.94564    0.650952    -1.45269    0.1463  -0.139575726
CAB -5.32912    4.25525 -1.25236    0.2104  -0.786578555
NOM -1.24661    1.014906    -1.2283 0.2193  -0.183999931


McFadden R-squared  0.671579    Mean dependent var  0.179487    
Log likelihood -12.0557             
LR statistic    49.30457    Avg. log likelihood -0.15456    
Prob(LR statistic)  0               
10%  Level of significance
```

These are my results. `Poverty` is my dependent variable and `EOH` denotes education of household head (independent). By taking the dummy variable:

1. Is it true if I `interpret:EOH` as possessing a significant coefficient with negative `sigh` (-0.094)? Here does the negative `sigh` shows that if education of household head increase, poverty will decrease or the probability of being poor will decrease? The negative coefficient -0.094 means that if EOH increase by one unit on average (other variables held constant), that has no educationent the estimated logit(pov) will decrase by 0.094 units suggesting a negative relationship between the two?
2. As we take the marginal effect that shows a household with an educated household head has greater ability to get rid of poverty 0.013 times than household that has no education?